# Selenium doesn't load the proper results when reaching the page, compare to manual load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm in an interesting situation here!
I'm trying to scrape from the onlyfinder.com, the links for the accounts from Onlyfans but I'm getting a completely different result from using selenium, compare to making the research manually (without selenium).

I'm getting the same "error" with both Chrome and Firefox so I don't know what else to do.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
import os, sys
from selenium import webdriver

#HERE IT FINDS THE PATH
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    try:
        app_full_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
        application_path = os.path.dirname(app_full_path)
    except NameError:
        application_path = os.getcwd()

#Here we create the variable that is going to be used to all the functions for the path
path = os.path.join(application_path)


#Here it takes the Chrome Path
chrome_path = (path + "\\chromedriver.exe")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.headless = False
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chrome_path)
browser.get("https://onlyfinder.com/profiles?q=Aaliyah%20Hadid")
```

**Here is the manual result:**
[image: Manual result]

**Here is the selenium result:**
[image: Selenium result]

Does anybody know why this is happening and how can I bypass it?

Comment: When you are manually searching then the search value is getting assigned with the `data-username` attribute, and it is getting displayed, but when you're performing the same with the selenium the `data-username` attribute is not getting assigned the search value and it displayed nothing, This what I found

Comment: @YaDavMaNish this is something that I have found too, but I want to know the reason for this

Comment: Well, you mentioned why this is happening in your question that's why I commented here, if you know this is happening in the background pls update your question.

Comment: @YaDavMaNish well I also mentioned if you know how can I bypass it. Maybe they block the selenium use. Maybe it's something else I don't know. 
But it's ok thank you for your time for real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check with the below `ChromeOptions()`, I think the site is
detecting the selenium and not allowing to assign the searched
value to the `data-username` attribute

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

Comment: You are the best man for real. I was crushing my head for HOURS